# Will Hegelian or Dialectical historiography regain any relevance into the contemporary historical discourse?

Tags: historiography

Much of contemporary Western historiography and historical analysis is dominated by either the Post-Modern or Marxist approaches.  Of course, Karl Marx was deeply influenced by George Hegel, however, Hegelian Dialectics is still an independently original school of historical thought and analysis. Can Hegelian-(NON-Marxist) dialectics regain its influence within contemporary historical discourse or has such a school of a thought gone the way of the dinosaurs?

Will Hegelian/Diaectical Historiography be revitalized in the near future? In other words, are there any signs within the recent historical literature or curricula which indicate a Hegelian renaissance? From my what I have seen and currently see, it does not appear to be the case. Perhaps you disagree and can provide me with some evidence which does indicate that there is a Hegelian or dialectical renaissance?

Comment: Can you please name one specific example of what you have in mind? E. g. a Hegelian non-Marxist historian?

Comment: Questions about the future are usually matters of opinion. Maybe you want to know whether any historians are following the Hegelian model today?

Comment: I’m a little surprised no one has mentioned Francis Fukuyama. There are no “pure” Hegelians that I’m aware of, but Hegel’s ideas often hover implicitly behind progress narratives, and many of the questions he raised (or gave recognizably modern form to) remain live ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hegel still has a great deal of influence in the sub-disciplines of the "History of Ideas."  However, Hegels grand theory of History as a philosophical concept has almost no use in contemporary work and the dominant anglophone historically methods. The philosophical concept of "history" doesn't resemble the disciplinary practice of historians. Gyorgy Lukacs is as far from EP Thompson as Hegel is from the history of ideas.

One issue to consider though is the triumphalism present in anglophone "Whig" historians of either the Tory or Whiggish political perspective: America fuck yeah, with your choice of whom "America" is.

Answer (score -5):

There are signs of interest in what is referred to in philosophy as the Hegelian Dialectic. Interestingly, for individuals who had not read Hegel previously, some cite the late hip-hip artist Prodigy of Mobb Deep as the individual which lead them to even be aware of the Hegelian Dialectic,  see [What is the Hegelian Dialectic?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_F4WomLlq0)

> Phaedon Lomis 1 year ago
>
> Prodigy (Mobb Deep) brought me here

as they titled their last album *[The Hegelian Dialectic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsdaXeNcZTA&list=PL2CHQ4dfgkcZuGKXEXudkC6nAFfX4hCAa)* which includes songs directly addressing the political application of the dialectic, including *Tyranny*, *No Religion*, and *Make America Great Again: Mafuckin U$A* et al., and described how they interpreted the Hegelian Dialectic, see [Hegelian Dialectic Explained With Prodigy Of Mobb Deep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=di5K-kbakqE).

What is also interesting is the varied ways that people describe [Hegel's Dialectics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-dialectics/).

Specifically relating to Prodigy of Mobb Deep, given that they have an international fan base used to them including lyrics in their work that is particularly thought provoking, e.g., from the 1995 remix of L.L. Cool J's *I Shot Ya*

> Illuminati want my mind, soul, and my body
>
> Secret society, trying to keep they eye on me
>
> But I'm stay incogni', in places they can't find me

see [What's Behind Hip Hop's Illuminati Music Obsession?](https://www.complex.com/music/hip-hop-illuminati-obsession).

It is perhaps beyond the scope of this question to demonstrate the international influence that Prodigy of Mobb Deep *has*. Suffice to say that his decision to title his last album *The Hegelian Dialectic* has and will have a direct impact on the number of people (e.g., [Prodigy Hegelian dialectic album and how it's philosophy controls America](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUHPsFh0XJQ)) who become aware of and study both Hegel and his dialectic.

Comment: A Prodigy album as your one and only example of "contemporary historical discourse" is a bit on the weak side. Such discourse is usually done by historians, not hip hop aficionados

Comment: I would prefer you not getting personal about it, or judging my "capacity to understand". An artist's lyrics are, at best, a sidenote in "contemporary historical discourse". He might have brought people into _contact_ with Hegel, but I don't think he'll be cited, or invited to any historian convention for his efforts.

Comment: @DevSolar Prodigy has already been cited by a historian, at this answer. We do not need to wait for your or anyone else's approval - first of all, no one asked you or anyone else. We do not rely on western academia for anything. And no one is interested in being "invited" to some "convention". You do not own history. We write our own history without any deference to you or western academia in general, as western academia has proven to be adversarial to not only hip-hop culture, but any culture that challenges, rejects, refutes and does not fawn over western academic notions.

Comment: Neither the OP nor myself said anything about historical discourse being limited to "western academic notions". Science, by definition, knows no boundaries. That's why scientists of all fields communicate with each other, via papers, at conventions, and online as well. However, I get the impression that this "we" you are referring to does not mean the community of historical science, but something else entirely. I'll stop trying to prick your echo chamber now.

Comment: @DevSolar Then what was your point besides western academic notions? You could simply accept the fact that Prodigy made many aware of Hegel. Yet, you rejected that fact without any evidence.

Comment: I did not reject that Prodigy made some / many people aware of Hegel. I tried to point out that a hip hop album is at best a sidenote in what the OP was referring to as contemporary _historical_ discourse. As kind of an explanation for why this answer is harvesting downvotes.

Comment: It is somewhat interesting that you put so high notions on western entertainment produce. while being so dismissive of "western academia" at the same time. So... is the hip hop by Prodigy part of the historical discourse (and hence, by definition, at least partially academic, more specifically "western" academic, in nature), or not academic -- and hence part of history, but not historic discourse? You've painted yourself into a corner there...

Comment: @DevSolar The art of Prodigy of Mobb Deep on the album _Hegelian Dialectic_ is not "entertainment" from perspective here. The artist is no longer with us, though the art is. No, would not characterize the album as "western", which is essentially European and U.S. colonial military powers: the organized crime syndicate of white supremacy and their agents extended into all areas of human activity. Just because an individual is domiciled, resides or publishes their works in the wilderness of the so-called "western hemisphere" does not make their art or ideas an agency of anything "western".

Comment: You sure have an axe to grind there. Good luck bending reality to your views. Here's to hope that you don't bend too many others to your hate.

Comment: @DevSolar There is no "hate" involved. The previous comment is historical fact.

Comment: @DevSolar Resources to support _""western", which is essentially European and U.S. colonial military powers: the organized crime syndicate of white supremacy and their agents extended into all areas of human activity."_, _"There is no "hate" involved. The previous comment is historical fact"_: _The Indian Wars: A Change of Worlds_ by LionHeart FilmWorks (2016); _The West_ by Ken Burns (1996)